# Appending characters to a string, what is the difference?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
auto str = std::string();

auto a = 'a';
auto b = 'b';

//this gives the desired output
str = str + a + b;

//this gives some garbage value
str += a + b;
```

What is the difference between these two expressions semantically?

Isn't the second one evaluated also as: `str = str + a + b;` ?

Comment: `a + b` should be in your case (ascii) `97 + 98` so `195`.

Comment: Sheesh. What's wrong with simply writing `std::string str;`, `char a = `a`;`, and `char b = 'b';`? There's no need for this `auto` dance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//this gives some garbage value
str += a + b;
```

This is semantically same as

```
str = str + (a + b);
```

because all assignment operators have lower precedence than almost anything (C++ operator precedence table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)).

And adding two `char` together performs integer addition of the character codes, producing a higher char code, which is probably above ASCII range, so something which looks garbage or graphical symbol. On ASCII character encoding (basically all PCs use extension of that), `'a' + 'b' == 97 + 98 == 195`, which for example in Latin1 character set is `'Ã'`.

Answer (score 3):

Since + has greater precedence than +=, the two characters are added first. Your code is equivalent to:

```
str += (a + b);
```

This is clearly not what you want. The addition of the two char values gives a totally different char value as a result, not their concatenation (chars are not strings).

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you have `(str + a) + b`. If you change it to `str = str + (a + b)` you will get the same garbage result. `a + b` chars result to char with ASCII code 195 (97 + 98) and it is added to `str`.

Answer (score 1):

`str = str + a + b;` will be evaluated as `(str + a) + b`. The overloaded `+` operator on `std::string` for a `char` type will be used. And this will *concatenate* `a` to `str`. `b` will follow similarly.

The other expression is undefined if your `char` type is `signed` on your platform. This is because `a + b` is evaluated first, and this could overflow your `char` type on your platform. If `char` is `unsigned`, then the ASCII value 195 will be concatenated to `str`.